# How can I suppress warning messages emitted by Getopt::Std::getopts?

Tags: perl, silent, getopts

I have short script test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use locale;
use encoding 'utf-8';

use Getopt::Std;

getopts("dei") or print STDERR "TRALALALALA\n"; 
print"@ARGV\n";
```

I need to suppress `Unknown option:` messages generated by getopts and only get mine TRALALALALA on stderr.

Comment: from reading getopts source this is not possible without overriding `CORE::warn` or installing a warn handler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { };  # Supress warnings
    getopts("dei")
        or print STDERR "TRALALALALA\n";
}
```

Or you could even embed the "TRALALALALA" in the warn handler:

```
{
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { print STDERR "TRALALALALA\n" };
    getopts("dei");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also localize `*::STDERR` and open it to a buffer in a block like so:

```
@ARGV = qw(-i -a -g);
{   open( local *STDERR, '>', \(my $stderr)) 
        or warn( 'Could not open to string!' )
        ;
    getopts( 'ig' );
    say '$stderr=' . $stderr;
}

print STDERR 'STDERR => out';
```